# pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Bad level "<BUILT-IN FUNCTION ALL>"

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to make a connection between AWS Glue and Snowflake through a private link

I already have the VPC endpoint configured and I can connect from glue without using pyspark

The code is the following:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import re

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
key_file = """-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
"""
p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
str.encode(key_file),
password="<pass>".encode(),
backend=default_backend()
)

pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)

pkb = pkb.decode("UTF-8")
pkb = re.sub("-*(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-*\n","",pkb).replace("\n","")



sfOptions = {
"sfURL" : "",
"sfUser" : "",
"pem_private_key": pkb,
"sfDatabase" : "",
"sfSchema" : "",
"sfWarehouse" : "",
"continue_on_error": "",
"sfAccount" : "",
"tracing": all,
}

query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table"
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query",  query).load()
df.show()

job.commit()
```

The JARS versions I am using are:

- snowflake-jdbc-3.13.22.jar
- spark-snowflake_2.12-2.11.0-spark_3.3.jar

I currently have the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test snowflake.py", line 79, in <module>
    df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query",  query).load()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 210, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Bad level "<BUILT-IN FUNCTION ALL>"
```

So far I have changed the query several times and tried with different versions of JARs but the error still does not change

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate this problem with `snowflake-jdbc-3.13.30.jar`, `spark-snowflake_2.12-2.13.0-spark_3.3.jar`. Changing `"tracing": all` to `"tracing": "all"` solved the problem for me, or removing the `tracing` option.